# Can a broken transport prevent SFTP put?

Tags: java, sftp

#### Background:

I am using `net.schmizz.sshj.sftp.SFTPClient` to SFTP numerous files daily - all to different destinations. All of the files transfer without error, except for one file which seems to transfer and then throw a broken transport exception after the file is sent (so it has been ignored).

Checking the logs, it looks like this file - and only this file - has been raising broken transport connection exceptions every day. However, the file is still being sent (because the logs say so, and the customer has received the file).

#### Issue:

Yesterday, the customer claims they did not recieve the file. So I am wondering if the issue is on their end, or perhaps:

*Can failing to cleanup the SFTP session cause the file to not be sent - even after the PUT succeeds?* What can I do to prevent this exception?

#### Code (simplified):

This code block works fine for all files except the aforementioned file.

```java
try {
  sftpClient = sshClient.newSFTPClient();

  // Transfer the file(s)
  if (getPut == SFTP.ACTION_PUT) {
    sftpClient.put(srcFilename, dstFilename);
    log.info("file sent");
  }
} catch (Throwable t) {
  log.error("failure", t);
} finally {
  try {
    if (sftpClient != null) { sftpClient.close(); }
  } catch (Throwable t) {
    log.error("could not clean up SFTP session", t);
  }
}
```

#### Logs:

The logs show that the file was sent, and that `sftpClient.put(srcFilename, dstFilename);` executed:

```
2020-03-04 17:38:36,398 [main] INFO  com.myPackage.SFTP - file sent
2020-03-02 17:42:04,690 [main] ERROR com.myPackage.SFTP - Could not clean up SFTP session
net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException: Broken transport; encountered EOF
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException$1.chain(ConnectionException.java:32)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionException$1.chain(ConnectionException.java:26)
    at net.schmizz.concurrent.Promise.deliverError(Promise.java:95)
    at net.schmizz.concurrent.Event.deliverError(Event.java:74)
    at net.schmizz.concurrent.ErrorDeliveryUtil.alertEvents(ErrorDeliveryUtil.java:34)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.AbstractChannel.notifyError(AbstractChannel.java:238)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.channel.direct.SessionChannel.notifyError(SessionChannel.java:229)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.common.ErrorNotifiable$Util.alertAll(ErrorNotifiable.java:35)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.connection.ConnectionImpl.notifyError(ConnectionImpl.java:258)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportImpl.die(TransportImpl.java:601)
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:65)
Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.transport.TransportException: Broken transport; encountered EOF
    at net.schmizz.sshj.transport.Reader.run(Reader.java:57)
```

Comment: I suspect that the customer may be closing the client before I get a chance to.

Comment: Try sshClient.disconnect() instead of sftpClient.close()